Jetpack compose preview for screen that have SharedTransitionScope, AnimatedVisibilityScope as parameter
I have this implementation for my Screen that use shared element transition
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun NoteContent(
    state: NoteState,
    query: String,
    onOrderChange: (NoteOrder) -> Unit,
    onToggleOrderSectionClick: () -> Unit,
    onDeleteClick: (Note) -> Unit,
    onUndoClick: () -> Unit,
    navigateToAdd: () -> Unit,
    navigateToEdit: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
    onQueryChange: (String) -> Unit,
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedVisibilityScope: AnimatedVisibilityScope
) {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val staggeredGridState = rememberLazyStaggeredGridState()

    with(sharedTransitionScope){
        Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = navigateToAdd, containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add Note")
                }
            },
            snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState) },
        ) { padding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            ) {

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
                    state = staggeredGridState,
                    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 4.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
                    verticalItemSpacing = 4.dp
                ) {
                    item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
                        SearchBar(
                            query = query,
                            onQueryChange = onQueryChange,
                            onToggleOrderSectionClick = onToggleOrderSectionClick
                        )
                    }

                    item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
                        AnimatedVisibility(
                            visible = state.isOrderSectionVisible,
                            enter = fadeIn() + slideInVertically(),
                            exit = fadeOut() + slideOutVertically()
                        ) {
                            OrderRadio(modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 8.dp),
                                noteOrder = state.noteOrder,
                                onOrderChange = { order ->
                                    onOrderChange(order)
                                })
                        }
                    }



                    items(state.notes, key = { it.id ?: 0 }) { note ->
                        NoteItem(note = note,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(4.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .animateItem(
                                    placementSpec = tween(
                                        durationMillis = 300, delayMillis = 0
                                    )
                                )
                                .sharedBounds(
                                    rememberSharedContentState(key = "note/${note.id}"),
                                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                    enter = fadeIn(),
                                    exit = fadeOut(),
                                    resizeMode = SharedTransitionScope.ResizeMode.ScaleToBounds()
                                ), // This line adds the placement animation
                            onDeleteClick = {
                                onDeleteClick(note)
                                scope.launch {
                                    val result = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                        message = "Note deleted", actionLabel = "Undo"
                                    )
                                    if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                                        onUndoClick()
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            onClick = {
                                note.id?.let { it1 -> navigateToEdit(it1, note.color) }

                            })
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


And i want to make preview of this screen or the content of the screen but idk what to pas for SharedTransitionScope, AnimatedVisibilityScope parameter in preview
fun NoteContentPreview() {
    NotedTheme {

        NoteContent(
            state = DummyNote.dummyNoteState,
            onOrderChange = {},
            query = "",
            onToggleOrderSectionClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            onDeleteClick = {},
            onUndoClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            navigateToAdd = { /*TODO*/ },
            navigateToEdit = { _, _ -> /*TODO*/ },
            onQueryChange = { },
            sharedTransitionScope = ,
            animatedVisibilityScope =
            )
    }
}

anyone know how to solve this without mocking any parameter or i must mocked them to make preview of the screen?, Thank you in advance
I can show Preview for the compose Screen

I am facing the same issue as you since I am implementing shared transition on an app that has previews for every screen. I couldn't find a less verbose solution, but what has worked is to wrap all screens inside the preview composables with SharedTransitionLayout{} and AnimatedVisibility(true){} and pass the scopes to the composable functions.
To make it a bit less verbose you can make your composable screens be an extension function of SharedTransitionScope.
This is how it looks like for me
@Composable
fun SharedTransitionScope.MyScreen(animatedVisibilityScope:AnimatedVisibilityScope){}

@Composable
@Preview
private fun Preview_MyScreen() {
    SharedTransitionLayout {
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = true) {
            MyScreen(animatedVisibilityScope = this)
        }
    }
}

Interested in knowing if there are better ways to do this as well.

Thanks, I didn't think of this kind of solution, but yeah, I hope there's a better one.

In case anyone needs simpler, straightforward solution: I made a demo project
My solution is to use CompositionLocal instead of passing down parameters to screen,inner composables. As I create ScreenContent composable in each Screen composable without DI-dependent objects like VM, passing those parameters around will be hell in deep hierarchy. With CompositionLocal we can easily provide SharedTransitionScope, AnimatedVisibilityScope scopes to any composable when needed and preview them without any boilerplate.
Depending on your navigation solution you have to create your own way to provide AnimatedVisibilityScope. I provided a demo with Jetpack Navigation Component (version 2.8.0).
SharedTransitionScope is easier to provide in your theme and start preview composables with the theme as usual. Here is the some bits from demo
LocalAnimatedVisibilityScope.kt
val LocalAnimatedVisibilityScope = compositionLocalOf<AnimatedVisibilityScope> {
    error("Must be provided first")
}

@Composable
fun AnimatedVisibilityScope.ProvideAnimatedVisibilityScope(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalAnimatedVisibilityScope provides this,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun WithAnimatedVisibilityScope(block: @Composable AnimatedVisibilityScope.() -> Unit) {
    with(LocalAnimatedVisibilityScope.current) {
        block()
    }
}


LocalSharedTransitionScope.kt
val LocalSharedTransitionScope = compositionLocalOf<SharedTransitionScope> {
    error("Must be provided first")
}

@Composable
fun SharedTransitionScope.ProvideSharedTransitionScope(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalSharedTransitionScope provides this,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun WithSharedTransitionScope(block: @Composable SharedTransitionScope.() -> Unit) {
    with(LocalSharedTransitionScope.current) {
        block()
    }
}

@Composable
fun OurComposeTheme(
    ...
) {
    ...

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = ...,
        typography = ...,
    ) {
        SharedTransitionLayout {
            // ProvideSharedTransitionScope wraps both preview and production code to provide SharedTransitionScope
            ProvideSharedTransitionScope {
                // As there is no NavHost used in Previews, we need to provide dummy AnimatedVisibilityScope ourselves
                if (LocalInspectionMode.current) {
                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = true,
                        label = "LocalAnimatedVisibility"
                    ) {
                        ProvideAnimatedVisibilityScope(content)
                    }
                } else {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

NavHost(navController, startDestination = Home) {
                    composable<Home> {
                        // This one is to provide Navigation's AnimatedVisibilityScope to deeply nested hierarchy,
                        // so forgetting it will cause a crash when WithAnimatedVisibilityScope used in this screen
                        ProvideAnimatedVisibilityScope {
                            HomeScreen(
                                onNavigateToProfile = { navController.navigate(Profile) }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    composable<Profile> {
                        ProvideAnimatedVisibilityScope {
                            ProfileScreen()
                        }
                    }
                }

usage:
@Composable
private fun ScreenContent() {
    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            // The content that is being shared
            WithSharedTransitionScope {
                WithAnimatedVisibilityScope {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedElement(
                                state = rememberSharedContentState(key = "shared_content_key"),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = this
                            )
                            .background(Color.Red)
                            .size(300.dp)

                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Preview it easily with no additional code as long as you start with the theme (I assume you already do so)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ScreenContentPreview() = OurComposeTheme {
    ScreenContent()
}

